# Execute Makefile rule only once

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a Makefile rule like the following:

```
%.b : %.a
    [run some commands...]
```

I'd like to rewrite my Makefile such that all conversions from %.a to %.b are handled by a single execution of the commands rather than once for every file.

I've tried the following:

```
%.b : someDummyFile

someDummyFile : 
    [run some commands]
```

The problem is that the rule for creating someDummyFile gets executed even when the first rule doesn't request it, leading to undesirable behavior.  I'm guessing that rules without dependencies get executed all the time even when their targets are not used by some other rule?

What am I missing here?

---

In trying to debug this problem, I removed all references to the second rule. For instance, I insert the following rule into an existing Makefile, why does it get executed even when no other rules make reference to it?

```
HELLOWORLD :
    echo "# HELLO WORLD! THE NEXT LINE WILL TRIGGER AN ERROR"
    DFASDA
```

Comment: What you're describing seems to work fine here; can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: @CarlNorum:  Thanks for checking this out.  My problem is that the rule is getting executed when I don't expect it to.  See my little example that I appended above.

Comment: If a rule isn't referenced, its recipe should never be executed.  You can use `make -d` to get a huge amount of debugging spew to help you track down why that happened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a quick example that I think does what you're looking for:

```
all: file1.x file2.x

%.x: doWork
    :

doWork:
    touch file1.x
    touch file2.x
```

The `doWork` rule will get run once, and then the `:` (no-op) in the `%.x` rule gets run twice.  You do need the `:`, or at least *something* as a recipe for that rule, or else you'll get an error about there not being a rule to make the `.x` file.  That's a side effect of the syntax used to cancel a pattern rule being a recipe-less rule.

Comment: @Basile - yes, `all` and `doWork` should both be `.PHONY`, but unless files with those names exist, it's not really that important.  I left the `.PHONY` line out for a minimum length answer.